# Are two subgroups of a finite $p$-group $G$, of the same order, isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Given $G$, $|G|=p^n$, $H,K\le G$ s.t. $|H|=|K|=p^k$ for some $k<n$.

Can we say that $H\simeq K$? I think it's true and I tried to prove it building by hand the isomorphism $\psi:H\longrightarrow K$ and working by induction on $k$: in fact every $p$-group (such $K$ and $H$ are) contains an element of order $p$; call them $h\in H$ and $k\in K$: I can make correspond these two elements in the isomorphism $\psi$.

Then I can consider the quotient groups $H/\langle h\rangle$ and $K/\langle k\rangle$ that are isomorphic by inductive hypotesis... and then? Can I conclude that $H$ and $K$ are isomorphic too?

Comment: No, this fails for plenty of examples (try a few of order $8$).

Comment: No, consider $G=\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ of order $8$.

Comment: I think it might actually be possible to completely classify $p$-groups satisfying this. A first step is noting that it is easy to see when it holds for abelian groups, and for $p=2$ the only other possibility is being generalized quaternion (so one needs to check if those satisfy it). For $p\geq 3$ a non-abelian example will have all elements of order $p$.

Comment: Take the direct product of two non-isomorphic $p$-groups of the same order.

Comment: @DietrichBurde:why $\mathbb Z_4\times\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$ has order $8$? Doesn't it have order $16$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I'd upvote such a question :-)

Comment: @JackSchmidt So would I. I don't feel like asking it myself because I would feel obliged to dig a bit deeper than what I wrote above, and I don't have the time for that right now (I suspect these groups are fairly rare).

Comment: But... I posted this question because I want to show that every finite $p$-group has normal subgroups of index $p^2$; and I'm able to show that every $p$-group has normal subgroups of index $p$, so if my conjecture were true I would conclude that the lattice of subgroups of a finite $p$-group is indeed a chain (up to isomorphism) and then, since I know that does exist a normal subgroup of order $p^{n-1}$ (i.e. the group of index $p$) then I can conclude that the subgroup of order $p^{n-2}$ (i.e. the sbgr index $p^2$) is contained in a normal one, hence it's normal.

Comment: Can someone help me with this, please? Thank you!

Comment: The lattice of subgroups is not a chain. Study $C_4$ and $C_2 \times C_2$ a little bit to get a feel. The dihedral and quaternion groups of order 8 are also good groups to understand concretely and thoroughly.

Comment: Yeah now I know that... but it's exactly for this reason that I can't prove what I want, i.e. to show that every finite p-group has normal subgroups of index $p^2$. And it's always for this reason that I wrote a long comment: in order to explain what my real problem is! Thanks

Comment: For that, an argument by induction will work to show that it in fact has a normal subgroup of order $p^k$ for any $k$ (with $0\leq k\leq n$).

Comment: Yes, like this: http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/a-p-group-contains-subgroups-of-every-order-allowed-by-lagranges-theorem/  
but I can prove the normality only considering subgroups of $G/Z(G)$; when we consider $Z(G)$ we can't apply the same argument since normality is NOT a transitive property! How can I do?

Comment: @Joe: You are right that normality is not transitive. But any subgroup of $Z(G)$ is a normal subgroup! Here is an idea for a similar proof: take $H \leq Z(G)$ of order $p$. Then $H$ is a normal subgroup. To finish the proof, apply induction to $G/H$.